# jade templating system hides div elements automatically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have this jade script and I'm trying to hide the 'menu', but it keeps hiding the copy div as well.

```
        #copy
        h1 <span style="color:yellow">Hello</span>
        #menu.hidden
              p.we_are We are
              p.approach Our Approach
              p.we_love We Love
              p.our_team Our Team
              p.learn_more To Learn More
```

When it compiles to html it hides the copy div as well - I'm not sure if it has something to do indentation. Thanks for your help

Comment: By "hides" do you mean "does not render HTML for?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you look at the source? There's nothing in #copy unless you indent the next line.

```
#copy
    h1
        span(style='color:yellow') Hello
```